# Problema con mi página al querer cargar los html parciales desde ui router

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-carousel

Estoy usando `ui-router` para insertar html parciales a mi `index.html` pero me está dando errores y no cargan, en mi máquina local sí funciona correctamente usanto `wamp`, pero al subir el sitio a `hostinger` me da estos errores. También estoy usando bootstrap. Alguien me puede ayudar?

> jquery.min.js:2 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://www.solucionesit.com.gt/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
>   jquery.min.js:2 OTS parsing error: invalid version tag
>   jquery.min.js:4 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
>   (program):304 WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.

```js
// app.js

var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
    
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
 
 $stateProvider
 
 .state('home',{
    url: '/',
       templateUrl : 'Html/home.html'
    })
 .state('about',{
    url: '/about',
    templateUrl: 'Html/about.html'
     });
 
 $locationProvider({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
  });
  
 
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="iso-8859-1">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
 <title>Soluciones de IT</title>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/styles.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
 <header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-sit">
      <span class="sr-only">Desplegar / Ocultar Menu</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>      
     </button>
     <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Soluciones de IT</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Inicia Menu -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-sit">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a ui-sref="Home">Inicio</a></li>
      <li><a ui-sref="About">Quienes Somos</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
       <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"> Productos <span class="caret"></span></a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a ui-sref="Equipo">-Equipos</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="UPS">-Power Bank </a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="accesorios">-Accesorios</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="Suministros">-Suministros</a></li>
       </ul>       
      </li>
      <li><a ui-sref="Servicios">Servicios</a></li>
      <li><a ui-sref="Contacto">Contacto</a></li>
     </ul>
     <form action="" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="buscar">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
      </button>
     </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
 </header>
 <section class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="col-md-10">
    <h1>Soluciones de IT</h1>
    <p>Soluciones integrales en tecnolog&iacute;a para su empresa<p>
   </div>
   <aside class="col-md-2">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/AQUI_TU_PAGINA" target="_blank"><img alt="Siguenos en Facebook" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-NSLbC_ztNls/T6VX0g6z8AI/AAAAAAAAA0A/_vyIBrmZbuY/s48/facebook48.png" width=48 height=48  /></a>
    <a href="http://twitter.com/AQUI_TU_USUARIO" target="_blank"><img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-vao9pzZoGtk/T6VYC4d1YMI/AAAAAAAAA0U/4rdP2chJido/s48/twitter48.png" width=48 height=48 alt="Síguenos en Twitter" /></a>
   </aside>   
  </div>
 </section>
 <div class="container">
  <section class="main row"> 
   <ui-view></ui-view>
   <aside class="col-md-2">
<div id="glbd-widget"><div id="glbd-load" style="width: 200px; height: 280px; background: url(http://globedia.com/img/loading.gif) center no-repeat;"></div><div id="glbd-link" style="text-align:right; font-size:10px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial; margin: auto; width: 200px;"><a href="http://globedia.com" title="Noticias" target="_blank" style="color:#999; text-decoration:none;">globedia.com</a></div></div><script type="text/javascript" src="http://globedia.com/widgets/widget.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://globedia.com/widgets/widget.php?country=0&category=ciencia-y-tecnologia&order=date&cols=1&num=4&width=200&height=280&title=Noticias%20Ciencias%20y%20Tecnolog&iacute;a&author=false&images=false&summaries=true&votes=false"></script><script type="text/javascript">GlobediaWidget.init();</script>
   </aside>  
  </section> 
 </div>
 
 <footer>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="main row">
          <div class="col-md-10">
           <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d482.6152573099787!2d-90.55149953598222!3d14.603515724926119!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1ses!2sgt!4v1467911973848" width="950" height="270" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
       </div>
     
         <div class="col-md-2">
        <h2>Soluciones de IT</h2>
        <address>
         <strong>20 Calle</strong><br>
         8-21<br>
         Zona 11<br>
         Colonia Mariscal<br>
         <abbr title="Email">Email:</abbr><a href:"mailto:luis.mejia@solucionesit.com.gt"> luis.mejia@solucionesit.com.gt</a><br>
         <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr> (502) 24727738
        </address>
       </div>
      </div>
  </div>
 </footer>
 
 
 <script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html
```

Answer (score 1):

El error que describes en palabras simples, dice que no puede descargar la fuenta desde la url http://www.solucionesit.com.gt/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf. Ademas agrega que esta petición puede no ser agradable a la experiencia del usuario. Debes descargar esa fuente, agregarla a tu proyecto y trabajarla en esa base, tu proyecto y no acceder a webs externas. Te funciona probablemente desde tu servidor ya que no tienes configurados cors para peticiones, pero una vez en un servidor normal, esto es impedido.

Answer (score 0):

por lo que dices que en tu Maquina si te funcionan pero en Hostinger no, tal vez se deba a que las rutas en Hostinger son diferentes, Estas usando alguna otra frame?

Prueba con Click Izquierdo , Insepccionar -> Luego ve a Nertwork y checa si al "entrar" a esas vistas parciales te aparece el nombre en rojo. si es así, la ruta esta mal.

Es todo lo que se me ocurre.